# Unity 3d: How can I initiate prefab in runtime without knowing the exact prefab I will use?

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, binary, gameobject

The code provided below doesn't seem to spawn an object from `prefabname` taken from file

```
void load()
{
    string[] files = Directory
        .GetFiles(Application.persistentDataPath, "*.furniture");

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
        Classforsavingdatafurnitures data 
            = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as Classforsavingdatafurnitures;
        stream.Close();

        // Create game object from prefab
        GameObject prefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>(data.nameofprefab);
        if (prefab != null)
        {
            GameObject obj 
                = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(data.position[0], 
                data.position[1], data.position[2]), 
                Quaternion.Euler(data.rotation[0], 
                data.rotation[1], data.rotation[2]));
            obj.name = data.nameofobject;
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to take from file `nameofprefab` and create an exact copy of an object in game. This code was was supposed to load from each file every object saved `.furniture`. 

Here is a [repo](https://github.com/piso101/Architect_N0) from GitHub if you need further information.

Comment: It appears that your troublesome code wasn't pushed to the git yet, so it's not that useful. Crate a branch and push your attempt to that, so you don't break your main branch. Right now I am interested in the `Classforsavingdatafurnitures` (long name) and the `Resources` folder that you may or may not have.

Comment: now repository is updated with new branch to download from. Feel free to investigate

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:
In "Savingandloadingfurniture.cs" you've misspelled `furnit*ur*e` as `furnit*ru*e`. If there is no such file the `foreach` loop doesn't even start.

Problem 2:
You need a "Resources" directory in your Assets. It must be called **exactly** that, but can be located in a sub folder and can exist multiple times. It should contain everything that you want to load. If you want to load something from the sub folder you will have to note the path.

Comment: can u check saving function ? is it right ? it is called in "statystykimebla"(eng.furniturestats) those functions should save rotation position name of prefab and name of gameobject and then if scene is loaded again it should load everything to scene to the same scene

Comment: Checking is a bit of an ask, since I don't know how this is supposed to work in the first place and half of the code is written in Polish. I've just opened the first scene, found a bed in the distance, self referenced it as the prefab (because there was an error), fixed the typo I mentioned and finally made a resource folder, where I put in the bed model. Two runs later a bed appeared, same place, same rotation, just bigger, because you don't save scale. Mission accomplished?

Comment: hopefully thanks !

Comment: voidsday can u create pull reguest for me ? cuz i cannot do your addjusments or i dont know how to